# Regular Expression Pattern To Accept An Apostrophe

Tags: regex

I am using Regular Expression in Jquery to validate names.I am having this issue that i need a pattern which will allow an apostrophe in the name.That means it can have alphabets and a single apostrophe.

```
Valid: D'souza,Danny
Invalid: D''souza
```

Can anybody help me out with this.Currently I am using this pattern

`var rxPattern = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$/;`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like that:

```
[a-zA-Z]+('[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*
```